# Adding Multiple Components to LinearLayout Programatically

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add multiple components into linear layout programatically. Here are the codes:

```
private View createCalloutView(Graphic graphic) {
    LinearLayout ret = new LinearLayout(this);
    ret.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView reportContent = new TextView(this);
    reportContent.setText(eventName + "\n" + eventBy + "\n" + eventAddress + "\n" + eventDesc
            + "\n" + eventDate + "\n" + eventTime);
    reportContent.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    reportContent.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
    reportContent.setPadding(1, 0, 1, 0);

    Button viewDtlEventBtn = new Button(this);
    viewDtlEventBtn.setText("View details");
    viewDtlEventBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ret.addView(reportContent);
    ret.addView(viewDtlEventBtn);
    return ret;
}
```

With these codes, I only manged to see the textview and my button is missing. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to set `ret.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`

Comment: [http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/add-a-textview-and-a-button-to-linear-layout-programmatically/](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/add-a-textview-and-a-button-to-linear-layout-programmatically/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that depends on how do you want to arrange the items in the `LinearLayout`. If you want to arrange the button next to the `TextView`, then, probably, the button width should be `WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `FILL_PARENT`. If you want to show the button under the `TextView`, then, your `LinearLayout` should have `vertical` as `orientation` (default is `horizontal`). Imo, the easiest way is to have your layout defined in a xml file. At least you can see the output at compile time, and use an inflater to retrieve the `View`'s object at run time

Comment: But I tried to customize the button by adding: viewDtlEventBtn.setBackgroundColor(color.lightpink);
  viewDtlEventBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); but it just showing a grey button with no text on it

Comment: what you mean by *then* ?

Comment: Sorry? but where is the then?

Comment: it was in your previous comment (before the editing). About your problem can you post the code that is displaying the grey button, without text ?

Comment: I added viewDtlEventBtn.setBackgroundColor(color.lightpink); viewDtlEventBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); but it does not show light pink color. I did declared the rgb for lightpink in my colors.xml

Comment: I see. Then you have to use `getResources().getColor(R.color.lightpink)`

Comment: Thanks it works! But one more question, I tried to set the minHeight but it does not work. The padding inside button is just way to large

Comment: minHeight to what ? button has no default padding and you are not setting any

Comment: There's some default padding top and bottom or maybe default height inside the button. When I set the text size smaller, the button height remains

Answer (score 0):

The default orientation of linear layout is horizontal. You need to set the orientation first.

```
LinearLayout ret = new LinearLayout(this);
ret.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ret.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

This will solve your problem of missing button.

Comment: I tried to customize my button by adding: viewDtlEventBtn.setBackgroundColor(color.lightpink);
  viewDtlEventBtn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); but the button turns out to be in grey with no text on it

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to set Layout Orientation for Linear Layout, just set it as below:

```
ret.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```